# Neo4j 3.3.0 docker image with APOC - was successfully initialized, but failed to start

Tags: neo4j, graphaware, neo4j-apoc, neo4j-plugin

I try to add APOC to my Neo4j instance from Neo4j 3.3.0 docker image but during the startup, I received the following error:

```
neo4j-database> 2017-12-11 19:57:01.189+0000 ERROR [c.g.r.b.RuntimeKernelExtension] Could not start GraphAware Runtime because the database didn't get to a usable state within 5 minutes.
neo4j-database> 2017-12-11 19:57:01.192+0000 ERROR Failed to start Neo4j: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@498f5728' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Cannot inherit from final class". Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@498f5728' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Cannot inherit from final class".
neo4j-database> org.neo4j.server.ServerStartupException: Starting Neo4j failed: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@498f5728' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Cannot inherit from final class".
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.server.exception.ServerStartupErrors.translateToServerStartupError(ServerStartupErrors.java:68)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:218)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:111)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.server.ServerBootstrapper.start(ServerBootstrapper.java:79)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.server.CommunityEntryPoint.main(CommunityEntryPoint.java:32)
neo4j-database> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase@498f5728' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Cannot inherit from final class".
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.server.AbstractNeoServer.start(AbstractNeoServer.java:210)
neo4j-database> ... 3 more
neo4j-database> Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error starting org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory, /var/lib/neo4j/data/databases/graph.db
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:211)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.newFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:126)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.server.CommunityNeoServer.lambda$static$0(CommunityNeoServer.java:58)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.server.database.LifecycleManagingDatabase.start(LifecycleManagingDatabase.java:88)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
neo4j-database> ... 5 more
neo4j-database> Caused by: org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifecycleException: Component 'org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures@6af29394' was successfully initialized, but failed to start. Please see the attached cause exception "Cannot inherit from final class".
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:466)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport.start(LifeSupport.java:107)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.initFacade(GraphDatabaseFacadeFactory.java:207)
neo4j-database> ... 9 more
neo4j-database> Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Cannot inherit from final class
neo4j-database> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
neo4j-database> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763)
neo4j-database> at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
neo4j-database> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467)
neo4j-database> at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73)
neo4j-database> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368)
neo4j-database> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362)
neo4j-database> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
neo4j-database> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361)
neo4j-database> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
neo4j-database> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
neo4j-database> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:411)
neo4j-database> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader$1.fetchNextOrNull(ProcedureJarLoader.java:141)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader$1.fetchNextOrNull(ProcedureJarLoader.java:118)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.collection.PrefetchingRawIterator.peek(PrefetchingRawIterator.java:50)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.collection.PrefetchingRawIterator.hasNext(PrefetchingRawIterator.java:36)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProcedures(ProcedureJarLoader.java:91)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.ProcedureJarLoader.loadProceduresFromDir(ProcedureJarLoader.java:82)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.proc.Procedures.start(Procedures.java:275)
neo4j-database> at org.neo4j.kernel.lifecycle.LifeSupport$LifecycleInstance.start(LifeSupport.java:445)
neo4j-database> ... 11 more
neo4j
```

I use the following plugins:

```
apoc-3.3.0.1-all.jar 
graphaware-neo4j-to-elasticsearch-3.3.0.51.7.jar 
graphaware-server-community-all-3.3.0.51.jar
```

Without `apoc-3.3.0.1-all.jar`  plugin everything is starting fine. Also, it is starting fine with only `apoc-3.3.0.1-all.jar` plugin without graphaware plugins.

What may be a reason of this issue ?

Comment: There is a related issue filed in the APOC github repo, but as of yet not a diagnosis or a fix available.  https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/issues/656

Comment: This has been fixed, you should be able to use it now with 3.3.1

Comment: Thanks! It is working now.