# Neo4j 3.3.1 - TransactionException: Unable to drop index on :Action(id): No such INDEX ON :Action(id)

Tags: neo4j

Due to the following issue [Neo4j 3.3.0 docker image with APOC - was successfully initialized, but failed to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47760619/neo4j-3-3-0-docker-image-with-apoc-was-successfully-initialized-but-failed-to) I moved to Neo4j 3.3.1-enterprise edition Docker image.

Right now I face the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.TransactionException: Unable to drop index on :Action(id): No such INDEX ON :Action(id).
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest.executeRequest(BoltRequest.java:170) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest.execute(BoltRequest.java:87) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.autoindex.AutoIndexManager.assertIndexes(AutoIndexManager.java:203) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.autoindex.AutoIndexManager.build(AutoIndexManager.java:93) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.session.SessionFactory.<init>(SessionFactory.java:84) ~[neo4j-ogm-core-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at com.example.domain.configuration.Neo4jConfig.sessionFactory(Neo4jConfig.java:33) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.domain.configuration.Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4b235c76.CGLIB$sessionFactory$2(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.domain.configuration.Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4b235c76$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$d47429d1.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:361) ~[spring-context-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    at com.example.domain.configuration.Neo4jConfig$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$4b235c76.sessionFactory(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_152]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:155) ~[spring-beans-5.0.1.RELEASE.jar:5.0.1.RELEASE]
    ... 68 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.ogm.exception.TransactionException: Unable to drop index on :Action(id): No such INDEX ON :Action(id).
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.transaction.BoltTransaction.commit(BoltTransaction.java:88) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-3.0.1.jar:na]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.request.BoltRequest.executeRequest(BoltRequest.java:151) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-3.0.1.jar:na]
    ... 83 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.neo4j.driver.v1.exceptions.DatabaseException: Unable to drop index on :Action(id): No such INDEX ON :Action(id).
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketResponseHandler.handleFailureMessage(SocketResponseHandler.java:83) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4-e82457a30ab1559d9dedfd9bbda9390bbe0b2920]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.unpackFailureMessage(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:470) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4-e82457a30ab1559d9dedfd9bbda9390bbe0b2920]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.messaging.PackStreamMessageFormatV1$Reader.read(PackStreamMessageFormatV1.java:431) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4-e82457a30ab1559d9dedfd9bbda9390bbe0b2920]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.receiveOne(SocketClient.java:191) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4-e82457a30ab1559d9dedfd9bbda9390bbe0b2920]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketClient.receiveAll(SocketClient.java:185) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4-e82457a30ab1559d9dedfd9bbda9390bbe0b2920]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.receiveAll(SocketConnection.java:203) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4-e82457a30ab1559d9dedfd9bbda9390bbe0b2920]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.SocketConnection.sync(SocketConnection.java:157) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4-e82457a30ab1559d9dedfd9bbda9390bbe0b2920]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.sync(ConcurrencyGuardingConnection.java:137) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4-e82457a30ab1559d9dedfd9bbda9390bbe0b2920]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.net.pooling.PooledSocketConnection.sync(PooledSocketConnection.java:157) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4-e82457a30ab1559d9dedfd9bbda9390bbe0b2920]
    at org.neo4j.driver.internal.ExplicitTransaction.close(ExplicitTransaction.java:115) ~[neo4j-java-driver-1.4.4.jar:1.4.4-e82457a30ab1559d9dedfd9bbda9390bbe0b2920]
    at org.neo4j.ogm.drivers.bolt.transaction.BoltTransaction.commit(BoltTransaction.java:74) ~[neo4j-ogm-bolt-driver-3.0.1.jar:na]
    ... 84 common frames omitted
```

This is very odd because my test fails every second execution. First time it's working fine and the next execution it's fails with the mentioned exception and right after that, it works fine again.

What may be wrong and how to fix it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue. I upgraded java libraries to latest versions and things started to work. Maybe it was a bug or incompatability between libraries and Neo4j version.